# Precipitation history of a city

Tags: statistics, weather

Does anyone know, if there's a site with precipitation (amount of rain in mm/inches) history for different cities? I need the data of Helsinki, Finland. I'm currently using Dark Sky [Forecast API](https://developer.forecast.io/) to get the current precipitation levels, but it doesn't seem to support that with history calls.

I'll cache the current values as they come, but can't get old data. I can update the database manually as a one off if I can get the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weather Underground has free historical data. Here's [data](http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/EFHK/2015/1/1/CustomHistory.html?dayend=18&monthend=6&yearend=2015&req_city=&req_state=&req_statename=&reqdb.zip=&reqdb.magic=&reqdb.wmo=) for Helsinki from January 1, 2015 through June 18, 2015 (for example). You can customize the data range and manually download as a CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

Wunderground Weather API .. maybe or

[National Climatic Data Center (NCDC)](http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/oa/ncdc.html)

Weather Underground sells an API, with a purchase option of historical data: http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/pricing.html

Also please take a look at these questions:

1. [Which weather data web services do you know?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8446360/which-weather-data-web-services-do-you-know?rq=1v)
2. [Are there any weather *history* apis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368722/are-there-any-weather-history-apis?rq=1)